# Multiply css value for child nodes in LESS

Tags: css, less

I have classes like below

```
.item-1{
  .child-item-1 {
     .child-item-2 {
    }
  }
}
```

I want to increase padding for each child something like that
  padding: (n*10)px

How can I get this as I have varied number of child items and for each child item I want to increase padding

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: For all the childs or specific class childs?

Comment: Added a solution for selecting childs with CSS selector `*`

Comment: @Troyer - I have iterative classes like     .child-item-1  , .child-item-2 and so on. I have N number of childs so how can I iterate the padding on it

Comment: .item-1{
  padding: @default-padding;
  .child-item-n {
      padding: @default-padding*10;
  }
}                                                                                                                          is there any option to make the class name as .child-item-n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a constant variable with `@` and just multiply it for the `n` number, in case you need to specify specific child classes you need to do like this:

```
@default-padding: 5px;

.item-1{
  padding: @default-padding;
  .child-item-1 {
      padding: @default-padding*10;
     .child-item-2 {
       padding: @default-padding*100;
    }
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.item-1 {
  padding: 5px;
}
.item-1 .child-item-1 {
  padding: 50px;
}
.item-1 .child-item-1 .child-item-2 {
  padding: 500px;
}
```

If you want to apply it to all the childrens you can use  `*` CSS selector like:

```
@default-padding: 5px;

.item-1{
  padding: @default-padding;
  & > * {
      padding: @default-padding*10;
     & > * {
       padding: @default-padding*100;
    }
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.item-1 {
  padding: 5px;
}
.item-1 > * {
  padding: 50px;
}
.item-1 > * > * {
  padding: 500px;
}
```